# Cannot select from parameterized type for Page type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

In a spring boot 3 application I have a method in a service layer

```
public Page<EditorRegistration> searchEditor(EditorSearch editorSearch, Pageable pageable) {
...
}
```

I try to do a test from controller

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class EditorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private EditorService editorService;

    @Test
    void searchEditorRegistration()  throws Exception{

        Page<EditorRegistration> mockEditorRegistration = Mockito.mock(Page<EditorRegistration>.class) ;

        String expected = "{....}";

        Mockito.when(editorService.searchEditor(Mockito.any(EditorSearch.class), Mockito.any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(mockEditorRegistration);


        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/editor/registristration").accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(expected));
    }
}
```

From this line

```
Mockito.mock(Page<EditorRegistration>.class) ;
```

I get

> Cannot select from parameterized type

Comment: Doing just mock(Page.class) doesn't work?

Comment: Cleaner level would be to add to class level where MockBean is
@Mock
private Page<EditorRegistration> pageMock;